# playing video When internet doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am developing android application about VideoPlayer. I play video on the internet,but I want to do play When android device doesn't connect to the internet. I think like that firstly I install video from intrnet in to the application and if internet exist on the device it plays from internet,but When internet doesn't exist it should be play in application How can I do this? My code is below

public class AndroidVideoPlayer extends Activity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener {

```
WakeLock wakeLock;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean pausing = false;;

Timer timer;

int maxVolume = 50;

int userInteractionTimeout;

Button sound;

int currentVolume;

String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ConnectivityManager cm;

NetworkInfo activeNetwork;
boolean isConnected;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    try {
        // REQUIRES ROOT

        Build.VERSION_CODES vc = new Build.VERSION_CODES();
        Build.VERSION vr = new Build.VERSION();
        String ProcID = "79"; // HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

        // v.RELEASE //4.0.3
        if (vr.SDK_INT >= vc.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            ProcID = "42"; // ICS AND NEWER
        }

        // REQUIRES ROOT
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[] {
                        "su",
                        "-c",
                        "service call activity " + ProcID
                                + " s16 com.android.systemui" }); // WAS
                                                                    // 79
        proc.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    Log.i("@mle", "" + isConnected);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "Full Wake Lock");

    sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_volume);
    sound.setOnClickListener(this);
    sound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sound.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    // AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)
    // getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    // currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    /*
     * timer = new Timer(); timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     * 
     * @Override public void run() { if (userInteractionTimeout == 15) { //
     * Do your @Override
     * 
     * timer.cancel(); Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
     * MainActivity.class); intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
     * intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     * startActivity(intent);
     * 
     * } userInteractionTimeout++; } }, 0, 1000);
     */

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

    // Displays a video file.
    VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    // String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.anket1/"
    // + R.raw.ucz_video;
    // Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    // mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);

    // mVideoView.requestFocus();

    if (isConnected == true) {

        DownloadFromUrl(url, "file");

        /*
         * mVideoView.setVideoPath(url);
         * 
         * mVideoView.start();
         * 
         * // video finish listener mVideoView .setOnCompletionListener(new
         * MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
         * 
         * @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // not
         * playVideo // playVideo();
         * 
         * mp.start(); } });
         */

    }

    else {

        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.anket1/"
                + R.raw.ucz_video;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.start();

        // video finish listener
        mVideoView
                .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // not playVideo
                        // playVideo();

                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    wakeLock.release();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;

    /*
     * case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // finger moves on the screen break;
     * 
     * case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // finger leaves the screen break;
     */
    }

    // tell the system that we handled the event and no further processing
    // is required
    return true;
}

public String DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {

    File SDCardRoot = null;
    try {
        SDCardRoot = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File files = new File(SDCardRoot + fileName);
        int sizeoffile;
        if (!files.exists()) {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory();

            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath());
            if (dir.exists() == false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl);
            File file = new File(dir, fileName);

            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            sizeoffile = ucon.getContentLength();
            Log.d("SIZEOFFILE: ", sizeoffile + " BYTE");
            /*
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            /*
             * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to
             * read(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }
            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return SDCardRoot + fileName;
}

/*
 * @Override public void onUserInteraction() { // TODO Auto-generated method
 * stub super.onUserInteraction();
 * 
 * userInteractionTimeout = 0;
 * 
 * // Log.d(LOG_TAG,"User Interaction : "+userInteractionTimeout);
 * 
 * }
 */

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_volume:

        Intent pas = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SetVolumeLevel.class);
        startActivity(pas);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to implement web-service for this. Which will download the video very first time if internet connectivity exist. Later when if network connectivity doesn't exist, play the video that you stored in your local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If internet available then first download video, you can use below codes:

```
public String DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {

    File SDCardRoot = null;
    try {
        SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File files = new File(SDCardRoot+fileName);
        int sizeoffile;
        if(!files.exists()) 
        {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

            File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
            if(dir.exists()==false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl);
            File file = new File(dir, fileName);

            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            sizeoffile = ucon.getContentLength();
            Log.d("SIZEOFFILE: ", sizeoffile+" BYTE");
            /*
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            /*
             * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }
            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return SDCardRoot+fileName;
}
```

Then Just check if internet available then play over internet else play the video that already on your sd.

Comment: is this code save url in sd cart? how can I save in android device not sd card

Comment: with android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), you can find which directory will be used

Comment: How can I define file in application? Can You show this?

Comment: what you mean with 'define file' ?

Comment: I created file.txt in my android project and I used your code,but I got error please look at my edit question

Comment: just add this method to your class then call it with your url that will downloaded

Comment: No I created in my android application "file.txt" file for the download url location but I have another problem I don't have sd card so I want to install to device memory and I used this        SDCardRoot = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory(); instead of  File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();   is it true?

Comment: I need to download video When internet exist and later when internet doesn't exist I want to play from downloaded location it could be android device memory

Comment: at com.example.anket1.AndroidVideoPlayer.DownloadFromUrl(AndroidVideoPlayer.java:261)

Comment: I shared last situation of code at above can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Determine if You Have an Internet Connection
There's no need to schedule an update based on an Internet resource if you aren't connected to the Internet. The following snippet shows how to use the ConnectivityManager to query the active network and determine if it has Internet connectivity.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Please check docs before asking on stackoverflow :-)

Cheers !

source : http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: I think the question is more "how to save a video" than "how to check for connectivity". Please check the question before answering on stackoverflow :-)